# Porting a simple algorithm to TPL with thread-local data

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cluster-computing

I have a very simple algorithm that clusters blobs based on their `x` and `y` distance to each other. I ported the same to use `Parallel.For` with thread-local data but the results were incorrect. In other words, I may not have used synchronization properly to isolate each thread.

Simply cannot figure out why the results of the two implementations are different. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I wanted to post fully compilable code but the objects used are too tightly integrated to the project context. Since the algorithm is very simeple, hopefully that will not get in the way.

**Class level declerations**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the master blobl collection to be clustered.
/// </summary>
public List<Blob> Blobs { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// List of clusters to be computed.
/// </summary>
public List<Cluster> Clusters { get; private set; }
```

**Linear Example (Works fine)**:

```
Cluster cluster = null;

for (int i = 0; i < this.Blobs.Count; i++)
{
    cluster = new Cluster();

    cluster.Id = i;

    if (this.Blobs [i].ClusterId == 0)
    {
        cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [i], i);

        for (int j = 0; j < this.Blobs.Count; j++)
        {
            if (this.Blobs [j].ClusterId == 0)
            {
                if (this.Blobs [i].Rectangle.IntersectsWith(this.Blobs [j].Rectangle))
                {
                    cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [j], i);
                }
                else if (this.Blobs [i].Rectangle.IsCloseTo(this.Blobs [j].Rectangle, distanceThreshold))
                {
                    cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [j], i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (cluster.Blobs.Count > 2)
    {
        this.Clusters.Add(cluster);
    }
}
```

**Parallel Port (Incorrect clusters)**:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For<Cluster>
(
    0,
    this.Blobs.Count,
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism },
    () => new Cluster(),
    (i, loop, cluster) =>
    {
        cluster.Id = i;

        if (this.Blobs [i].ClusterId == 0)
        {
            cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [i], i);

            for (int j = 0; j < this.Blobs.Count; j++)
            {
                if (this.Blobs [j].ClusterId == 0)
                {
                    if (this.Blobs [i].Rectangle.IntersectsWith(this.Blobs [j].Rectangle))
                    {
                        cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [j], i);
                    }
                    else if (this.Blobs [i].Rectangle.IsCloseTo(this.Blobs [j].Rectangle, distanceThreshold))
                    {
                        cluster.Blobs.Add(this.Blobs [j], i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (cluster);
    },
    (cluster) =>
    {
        lock (this.Clusters)
        {
            if (cluster.Blobs.Count > 2)
            {
                this.Clusters.Add(cluster);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You did notice that List<T> is not thread-safe?

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: That's right. However, as far as I can tell, `this'Clusters` is not being accessed from within the parallel body. That's why I only access it from the `localAction` body and lock it for good measure. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: yes, but Blobs is also a list, and I'm a bit confused if it's in the cluster (locally accessed within a thread) or not.

Comment: Both Clusters and Blobs are class level properties. `this.Blobs` is not being modified at all. `this.Clusters` is only being added to and that too from within the `localAction`. I see another potential problem though. The Blobs.Add method is overriden. You will notice two parameters. The second is the `ClusterId`. I can't see it but do you suppose that is problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is misunderstanding of that “thread-local data”. According to [the documentation of `Parallel.For()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx), it's:

> […] some local state that may be shared amongst iterations that execute on the same thread.

What this means is that some iterations of your loop will share the same `Cluster` object, which will cause incorrect results for you. If the `localInit` and `localFinally` executed for each iteration, then they would be useless, because you could do exactly the same thing by moving their code to the beginning and end of the loop.

The reason why the delegates are there is that you can use them for *optimization*. With them, you don't have to access shared state (in your case `this.Clusters`) as often, which can improve performance.

If you don't need this optimization, don't use the two delegates and instead write the body of your loop like this:

```
i =>
{
    var cluster = new Cluster { Id = i };

    // rest of the loop here

    if (cluster.Blobs.Count > 2)
    {
        lock (this.Clusters)
        {
            this.Clusters.Add(cluster);
        }
    }
}
```

(In the above code, I also switched the `lock` with the `if` as an optimization.)

If you think the optimization using thread-local data would be useful for you (i.e. it would actually speed things up), you can use it. But the data in question would have to be a list of `Cluster`s, not just a single `Cluster`. Something like:

```
() => new List<Cluster>(),
(i, loop, clusters) =>
{
    var cluster = new Cluster { Id = i };

    // rest of the loop here

    if (cluster.Blobs.Count > 2)
        clusters.Add(cluster);

    return clusters;
},
clusters =>
{
    lock (this.Clusters)
    {
        this.Clusters.AddRange(clusters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not yet understand the first half of your explanation but the last code snippet definitely is a clue to understand the former. The optimization with thread-local data is necessary, otherwise the gain from parallel processing is too small. I will implement your second example and revert back.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Ok, looking at the documentation and your example, I gather that the `final` would execute once per thread, therefore returning multiple clusters rather than a single cluster. I also presume that the `clusters` object in the loop body will be thread-specific. I have used Parallel.For with thread-local data before but am not sure why I implemented it this way.

Comment: Trying to implement for loop body and now I see why it seemed counter-intuitive to use `Parallel.For<List<Clusters>>` initially. In the body of the loop, I need each created cluster to hold a unique ID, which should then be passed on to the blobs it contains. While doing this in parallel, I don't see how that can be done. Perhaps I need to revisit the algorithm to make it a good candidate for parallel processing. Would you know of any distance-clustering algorithms that are suitable for parallel processing?

Comment: I don't understand why is that a problem. Isn't the index in the loop enough? Or you could have a global counter with synchronized access.

Comment: Turns out it was enough. Works perfectly and saves up to 50% time on larger images. Thanks!